# SCOM to Slack Integration

Tags: slack, scom

I want to integrate slack with SCOM. SO i have a powershell script which will post notifications to slack and i have found where to place it so that it will get executed when some error occurs. But I am unable to find a way to create a Custom rule for error generation (eg. I want to create a rule which will trigger when any machine configured in SCOM, goes down or when its CPU utilization goes down). So that when this rule breaks, my Powershell script for slack notification will get triggered. IS this possible in SCOM?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new command channel in SCOM
2. Attach the script that will process the alert's output ( the logic to both transform the data and send it to slack )
3. Create a subscription to the monitors and rules that you want passed to slack
4. Subscribe the command channel to the subscription

Reference: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fesiro/2012/11/26/how-to-configure-command-notification-in-scom-2012-with-powershell-script/

If you have Orchestrator in your System Center infrastructure you can make a runbook that is initialized by a SCOM alert. You will need to setup the SCOM connector if you haven't but this is a great way to make the process more easily managed. Then you can call your script inside the runbook.